# Cocoa binding working on 10.12 but not High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, cocoa, key-value-observing, cocoa-bindings, macos-high-sierra

As I already have some KVO problem in the past, it may not be a 10.13 beta bug.

To have the status of a process in real time, I've binded an NSImageCell value to an NSImage, and I'm assigning the value from another thread to Main Thread like this:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MyViewController sharedInstance].myStatusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStatusAvailable];
            });
```

It works perfectly on 10.12, but no image at all on 10.13 beta 2.

I've checked the value of myStatusImage and it's well assigned, it's the binding which doesn't work and not reflected on GUI.
Like if it wasn't sent on the Main Thread for ex.

I've tried `willChangeValueForKey:` `setValue:forKey:` `didChangeValueForKey:`, but nothing did it.

My image just doesn't appear in 10.13 beta 2.

Update: I realized that this refresh is made by a callback of an NSTimer.
Does it change something considering NSRunloop?
Still doesn't work in 10.13 beta 9

Update2: KenThomas solution worked: binding on NSImage instead of NSImageCell.
But there's still a problem with an NSButton and it's title bound to an NSString.
Title doesn't appear on view launch, but appears immediately as soon as I press ALT-TAB to switch to Finder for ex. Same: as if it wasn't made in main thread.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay`? (For `sharedinstance.view`?)

Comment: Good idea but it didn't help neither!

Comment: Too bad.  I am somewhat bothered by the dispatch_sync rather than async.  Any reason for sync?

Comment: I've updated my question when I realized these refreshes were made by an NSTimer callback.
Still doesn't work in 10.13 beta 9. Something to see with NSRunLoop?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you set up the binding on the image view itself rather than the image view cell?

Comment: Thanks, Yes it worked for my NSImage! Binding them to the view instead of the cell. There's still a last problem in 10.13 with one NSButton title, bound to an NSString, I tried on view and view cell, this time it appears but as soon as I change macOS view (ALT-TAB) or quit the view and enter another time. setNeedsDisplay didn't help as well...